# undefined method `user' for #<Class:0x00007ffbd1c309b8>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I don't understand why I can't use self here?

```
class PayoutRequest < ApplicationRecord
  validates :phone, confirmation: true, on: :create
  validates :phone_confirmation, presence: true, on: :create
  belongs_to :user, foreign_key: "user_id"
  validates :amount, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 300, smaller_than_or_equal: self.user.balance }

  scope :paid, -> { where(:paid => true) }
  scope :unpaid, -> { where(:paid => false) }
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `self` is not what you think it is. In case you didn't know or forgot, validation DSL is just methods called on the class itself. Here you basically call `PayoutRequest.validates` and pass it some parameters.

```
validates :amount, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 300, smaller_than_or_equal: self.user.balance }
^           ^ arg     ^ kw arg   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
method name                                 just a regular hash, defined at the class level. So `self` is the class.
```

Comment: then how I can write this?

Comment: You could use a custom method: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods. Those are executed at the instance level.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write this?

Use a custom method, for example:

```
validate :amount_not_greater_than_balance

def amount_not_greater_than_balance
  return if amount <= user.balance
  errors.add(:amount, "can't be greater than balance")
end
```

*In addition*, you should probably only run this specific validation rule `on: :create` -- because it would presumably be totally acceptable for a payment request to **become** more than the user's balance, later on n the future.

Comment: "to become less than the user's balance" - did you mean "more/greater" here? Overall, not sure about this suggestion. I guess I can't see why not run this validation on updates too. We never want to create a payment request that exceeds the user's balance or make it become such.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant more. Fixed.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Suppose a user has $100, and requests a payout of $80. Fine. $80 is paid out of their account, so now they only have $20 in the account. But does this mean their original `payout_request` should have **BECOME INVALID**??!

Comment: That's why I suggest such a validation only makes sense at the point of creation, not at an arbitrary point later in the future.

Comment: If it's moved to `pending` again, yes, it should be invalid. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Who said anything about a "pending" status? This seems like an extension to the design that OP never mentioned?... But OK, if you wanted to introduce such a step, then you could only run the validation *if the payment request is pending* instead of `on_create`.

Comment: Naturally, a payout request should have some kind of state machine. Anyhow, I think we're agreeing here, actually. I would remove the validations from the model and place them in the corresponding "operation". A payout request could have these operations: create, complete. Each with their own validations and logic. Which is a way to do the thing you're suggesting, but with more code. :)

Comment: "This seems like an extension to the design that OP never mentioned" - Ah, there is a state machine even here: paid/unpaid.